# How do I know (el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop +1).toFixed(0) >= el.clientHeight.toFixed(0) its greater than by 1 than return true onScroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**How do I know (target.scrollHeight - target.scrollTop +1).toFixed(0) >= target.clientHeight.toFixed(0) its greater than by only 1 than return true if its greater than 1 or any other value than it will return false.**

I was trying this code...

```
const handleScroll = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;

    if ((target.scrollHeight - target.scrollTop).toFixed(0) === target.clientHeight.toFixed(0)) {

      let pageNo = page + 1;
      if (pageNo <= pageCount) {
        fetchSuppliers(data , pageNo);
        setPage(pageNo);
      }
    }
  };
```

This code is not working on some chrome cause in **some big screen resolution the value is 201 === 200 so that time this code not working..****

so i have to try the greater than or equal condition but here has a fallback cause the left value will change on scroll like **800 >= 200** its giving true but i want when the value **201 or 202 >= 200** then it should return true otherwise return false

Help me on this regards
**Thank you all**